# REGEXP in MySQL does not understand cyrillic in square brackets. How to fix?

Tags: mysql, cyrillic

There is a code, it works, a lot of results are found:

```
SELECT *
FROM `modx_site_content` AS `msProduct` 
WHERE `msProduct`.`pagetitle` REGEXP '300х250х625'
```

But I want the number separator to be not only the Russian letter "x", but also the English "x" and the star symbol "*".

First, I change the code like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `modx_site_content` AS `msProduct` 
WHERE `msProduct`.`pagetitle` REGEXP '300[х]250[х]625'
```

I put the Russian "x" in square brackets. I ran a query and found 0 rows. MySQL does not understand Russian "x" in square brackets.

How to fix?

Table in this encoding: utf8_general_ci.
Table type: InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

you should use regex symbols:

```
SELECT *
FROM `modx_site_content` AS `msProduct` 
WHERE `msProduct`.`pagetitle` REGEXP '300[х].?250[х].?625'
```

if your MySQL version bigger than 8.0 you can use unicode in REGEXP:

```
\p{}    #Unicode character sets
\P{}    #negated unicode character sets
\u{}    #specify unicode characters using codepoints
```

Also you can use mysql LIKE operator

[MySQL 5.7 Pattern Matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

[MySQL 8.0 Pattern Matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: Why would `+` help? They want to match exactly 1 character, not 1 or more.

Comment: Based on the code they used, they are searching for something like this `300х250х625` right? after brackets we have another character , that's why we use `+`

Comment: That's not what `+` means. It means 1 or more of the previous pattern, so `[x]+` means 1 or more `x`, so it would match `300xxx250xxxxx625`

Comment: Their eventual goal is something like `\d+[x*]\d+[x*]\d+` so  the `x` character can optionally be `*` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works!
But does the "+" symbol mean 1 or more times? And that's not what I need. I need exactly 1 time.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I learned something from you.

Comment: I updated the answer, it matches exactly 1 character and works with old MySQL versions.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to MySQL 8.0.

If we test your string matching with MySQL 5.x, it does not work:

https://dbfiddle.uk/PmtEpS11

```
select '300Х250Х625' regexp '300[Х]250[Х]625' as `match`

+-------+
| match |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

But MySQL 8.0 changed the implementation of regular expressions to use a different library. The new implementation [supports multi-byte characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility). We test your string matching with MySQL 8.0, it works:

https://dbfiddle.uk/st0gsiJW

```
select '300Х250Х625' regexp '300[Х]250[Х]625' as `match`

+-------+
| match |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
```

So in MySQL 8.0, you can test all three characters you are interested in:

```
select '300x250x625' regexp '300[Хx*]250[Хx*]625' as `match`;

+-------+
| match |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
```